# How to filter a range of rows by position?

Tags: r

I have a excel sheet with 2 columns implemented into R with filepath as Excel.csv.
One column is 1_col and the other second column is 2_col.

These columns have 700 rows.
How do i only pull data from rows 350-500 ?

I also am attempting to write a statement that will tell me the row number minus one row if the value is less than 200 in the cell. Is there anyone that can help me with this function ?

I have

```
filepath = "Excel.csv"
data = read.csv(filepath) 

x<-c(data$1_col)
index <- match(TRUE,x<200
value<- x[index]
print(value)
```

This is giving me the value of the number less than 200 but i am trying to have the number the row is on minus one.

Comment: `mydf[350:500, ]`

Comment: Using `dplyr`: `mutate(mydf, newcol = if_else(x < 200, row_number() - 1, NA_integer_))`

Comment: See [`?Extract`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) (for `[`), [`?which`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html), and perhaps (though not required) [`?subset`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/subset.html) to learn how to subset your data based on various conditions, including inequalities. (`match` is not the right function for this.)